# CMS for Version Control System (subversion) - local google code analog

Tags: svn, content-management-system

I'm looking for CMS to make a web portal alike google code but for local project, for own subversion server.

I found the only one - opengrok, but it's based on Java and very hard to install.

Is there some CMS alike google code ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you check out Trac http://trac.edgewall.org/

It does most of that (and more), it's easy to maintain, etc.

Comment: it's looking like really great, I'm going to test it first.

Comment: Test it with multiple projects and sub projects. Also look at filtering issues, exporting summaries to pdf. Set up workflows and a roadmap. Finally switch on a discussion board / forum. If you struggle with any of these then take a look at Redmine. I've been there done that - switched to Redmine and never looked back. Just be aware Redmine has been forked, the alternative is ChiliProject.

Answer (score 1):

In work we use Teamforge along with various agile templates.
I believe jetbrains also have a product which is similar. I am unsure on licensing.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org), cause it can handle mutliple Projects with a single installation and support many VCS out of the box etc.